# How to select different row values in different column

Tags: sql-server

I have a table like.

```
ID  Date         Value
1   12/12/2014   A
1   24/12/2014   T
2   13/12/2014   A
2   23/12/2014   T
3   12/03/2014   A
3   12/04/2014   T
4   12/12/2014   T
5   12/04/2014   T
```

And i want result like where ADate is the Date where Value is A and TDate is the Date where value is T

```
ID    ADate            TDate
1     12/12/2014      24/12/2014
2     13/12/2014      23/12/2014
3     12/03/2014      12/04/2014
4         -           12/12/2014
5         -           12/04/2014
```

Comment: @NoIdeaForName How is that supposed to work?

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu well, with the given information, that's all i can provide

Comment: @NoIdeaForName If you're trying to help the OP out, just ask for more details. And if you do intend to troll at least make sure your query doesn't return a syntax error.

Comment: @Rain my answer does not use group by btw

Comment: @NoIdeaForName I'm running your query and checking. Actually i'm joining some more tables also so its returning some duplicate rows.Any way thanks for the answer

Comment: @Rain if you want to, i'll be happy to continue helping with some more information

Comment: what version of rdbms you're using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `conditional Aggregate`. Try this

```
SELECT id,
       Min(CASE
             WHEN value = 'A' THEN [Date]
           END) Adate,
       Max(CASE
             WHEN value = 'T' THEN [Date]
           END) Tdate
FROM   Tablename
GROUP  BY id
```

**Update : To get rows with same ID**

```
DECLARE @cnt INT

SELECT TOP 1 @cnt = Count(1) / 2
FROM   #test
GROUP  BY id
ORDER  BY Count(1) / 2 DESC

SELECT id,
       Min(CASE
             WHEN value = 'A' THEN [Date]
           END) Adate,
       Max(CASE
             WHEN value = 'T' THEN [Date]
           END) Tdate
FROM   (SELECT Row_number()
                 OVER (
                   partition BY id, value
                   ORDER BY date)%@cnt rn,
               *
        FROM   #test) a
GROUP  BY id,rn
```

Comment: I can't use group by because my actual table contains many rows with same ID and i want each ID, not in group.

Comment: @Rain Then add sample data and expected output accordingly!!

Comment: Got it. This gave me the correct answer.Although i need to tweak it a little for my purpose.Thanks

Answer (score 3):

you can use a WHERE statement and a JOIN statement to get:

```
SELECT a.id, a.date AS ADate, b.date AS TDate
FROM table a
JOIN table b on a.id = b.id and b.value = 'T'
WHERE a.value = 'A'
```

the WHERE statement make sure `ADate` comes from a row where `value='A'`.

the JOIN statement make sure  `TDate` comes from a row where `value='T'`.

Answer (score 0):

One more option with an ranking function ROW_NUMBER

```
;WITH cte AS
 (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY [date]) AS rn
  FROM dbo.test103 t  
  )
  SELECT c.id, c.[date] AS ADate, c2.[date] AS TDate
  FROM cte c LEFT JOIN cte c2 ON c.Id = c2.Id AND c.rn = c2.rn - 1 AND c.Value != c2.Value
  WHERE c.value = 'A'
```